# How to create a Google Form using Google Apps Script Execution API + Java?

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-api

I tried a simple Java command-line application that makes requests to the Google Apps Script Execution API. Something like this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/java#prerequisites. But it doesn't work.

Google Apps Script Editor:

```
function createForm() {

  var form = FormApp.create('New Form');

}
```

Java Error:

```
Credentials saved to /home/palmaslab/.credentials/script-java-quickstart.json
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at org.gradle.AppsScriptApiQuickstart.main(AppsScriptApiQuickstart.java:188)
```

Comment: we cant help if you dont show us the java code. Also tell us how you configured the script for execution api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have to authorize previously the scopes.
Maybe it could help you:
[Manual authorization scopes for Sheets, Docs, and Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts)

Answer (score 1):

API returning an `HTTP 401` response when calling the API. These error could indicate any of:

Token expiry, token revocation, token not authorized for needed scope, request not authorized correctly with [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). You may also check [`Forms Service`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/#classes) for more information regarding forms services

Here's a related issue of 401: Unauthorized: [Google apps script and execution API: latest version of script throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419614/google-apps-script-and-execution-api-latest-version-of-script-throws-error)