# Using the Google Scripts Execution API from an Android app

Tags: android-studio, google-apps-script

I am trying to write to a Google Spreadsheet and I found out about Google App Scripts and did the quickstart.  Now, I am trying to do call to my own Script, but whenever I do I get a 401 unauthorized error, but not when I use the quickstart script. I can run the script:

```
function myFunction()  {
var sheet = spreadsheetApp.openById('17it0wughXXbFMPVzVcU0pG5jAkiRZBRfH0ht4GXirWM');    
var range = sheet.getDataRange();  
sheet.getRange('b2').setValue('Hello');  
if(sheet.getRange('b2').getValue()==='Hello'){  
                             return 'success';  
                             }
```

}

directly from the script, but not from the app.  Does anybody know how to fix this?

I have the code:

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.openById('17it0wughXXbFMPVzVcU0pG5jAkiRZBRfH0ht4GXirWM'); 
}
```

and I get the error.  Then I change it to:

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet= DriveApp.getFileById('17it0wughXXbFMPVzVcU0pG5jAkiRZBRfH0ht4GXirWM') 
}
```

and no error.  However, I want to use SpreadsheetApp to call from my app.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[Error 401](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) means that you have an invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either expired or invalid. Found a possible workaround for your error in this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419614/google-apps-script-and-execution-api-latest-version-of-script-throws-error).

> The Execution API will use the currently published version of your script if devMode is false or omitted from the request. What I am suspecting is that there was a change of OAuth scopes in your script. The users's OAuth token needs to include all the scopes your project requires.
>
> Open your project's properties and click on the scopes tab. Make sure your java client's OAuth scope request matches what is in the list. You may have extra scopes in your client, but you need to at least include all that are in that list.
>
> Also in the Execution API deployment dialog there is an option limiting access to yourself, your domain, or anyone. Make sure the the user account you are using on the client matches your choice.

Also make sure that you enabled "Google Apps Script Execution API" in Developer's Console. Then check if under Credentials, you add a new "OAuth 2.0 client ID" credential. Check this [blog](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/3youw9/go_and_google_apps_script_execution_api/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I made sure of that, but the problem is only with spreadsheets.  I can call Drive, but not Sheets, and Sheets is in the scope list.